# Metro apps unable to connect

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, modern-ui, dell-studio

Ive got an active internet connection, and my browsers can access it. However, none of the metro apps are able to connect. They all indicate that the system is offline.

I'm quite sure it's because my network and sharing center says "No Internet Access" next to the "Access Type" and I have an exclamation mark next to the network icon in the system tray.

I've tried changing my IP address from static to auto and vice-versa, but the problem still persists.

Any idea how I can remove that exclamation mark?

System: Windows 8, Dell Studio 15.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: If it says `No Internet Access`, Metro won't work

Comment: I am behind a proxy, however, I'm avoiding the whole proxy problem by using a cascading proxy (using CCproxy).

Comment: I'm using CCProxy too. So if you are on ethernet, once you run CCProxy, disconnect and reconnect the cable. Don't know why but this works. For Wi-Fi, turn on Flight mode and then turn it off

Comment: What's your proxy server type?

Comment: Pratyush, I'll try that and reply back to you. As for my proxy type, I'm not sure, NTLM I guess. Asks for proxy auth.

Comment: Hi Pratyush, disconnecting and reconnecting didnt fix it...any other ideas?

Comment: Also, have you installed the Loopback utility?

Comment: Yep, Loopback was installed.